# How to save a JSON post request with a Flask server?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a simple web server built with Flask. The server listens for JSON post webhooks.

```
  @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

I need a way to save the incoming JSON data. I am not sure how to go about this. The data doesn't need to be put into tables or configured in anyway.

Comment: What do you mean save the incoming JSON data? Would you like to save the JSON as a file to the same directory that the Flask app is in (or a subdirectory)?

Comment: Yes, that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python's `logging` facility. An example code below, used from [Logging to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file) and your snippet shared above.

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request

logging.basicConfig(filename='requests.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_data = request.get_json()
        logging.info(request_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.info("Running application with local development server!")
    app.run()
```

The above code will log your requests with timestamps to a file and append to the file every time a new request is made.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

from flask import request, jsonify

````
def webhook():
    resp=''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form_field = request.form['my_form_field']
        if my_form_field:
            resp = 'Form data received'`enter code here`
            return jsonify(resp = resp) #you may collect this response with JQuery
        else:
            resp = 'Form field is empty'
            return jsonify(resp = resp)```
````